# Use a variable for remote_user in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to parameterize (use a variable) for `remote_user` in ansible.
This is the first part from the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: xxx
  remote_user: "centos"
  become: true
```

I will replace it with

```yaml
- hosts: wazuh
  remote_user: "{{ new_user }}"
  become: true
```

But what is a good place to store the value of this variable? It seems `group_vars/all` mostly contain variables which are more app/env specific than ansible specific. Or should I put it in `inventories/hosts` as a var? What is the recommended location to store it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually store it in your inventory as `ansible_user` either for the `all` group (for all host), a specific group or a specific host. You can keep a `remote_user` in your play which will be used in case the `ansible_user` is not defined for some hosts in your inventory. If you remove it, you local user on the controller will be the default, unless you use the `-u` flag on the command line.

You can find a good explanation of the difference between `ansible_user` and `remote_user` and how the overide works in [the documentation on variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)

Using a var as you wrote it in your above example can actually work. But since it must be expanded before the play actually starts and any action is taken on any host, the only place you can "store" it is in an `extra_var` on the command line.

To be a little more practical, here is what I suggest from your above example:

`inventories/dev/hosts.yml`

```yaml
---
wazuh:
  hosts:
    host_a.wazuh.tld:
    host.b.wazuh.tld:
```

`inventories/dev/group_vars/wazuh.yml`

```yaml
---
# Vars for the wazuh group
ansible_user: centos
```

`plabook.yml`

```yaml
---
- hosts: wazuh
  
  tasks:
    - name: Proove we connected with the given user
      cmd: whoami
      register: whoami_result
    
    - name: Show actual result
      debug:
        var: whoami_result.stdout
```

Launching the playbook:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/dev playbook.yml
```